# Memory leak with WebView in Android project

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am using a java project into and Android project. The java project uses the reference of the Activity object from the Android project(when i call a function on the java project, i send the Activity reference). So far it's ok, but sometimes an error appears. It's a memory leak:

```
    09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.test.android.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{425c0468 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-720,1280} that was originally added here
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:467)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at com.test.AppBase$5.run(AppBase.java:210)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4924)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at com.test.AppBase.setVisibility(AppBase.java:197)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at com.test.AppBase.callSmth(AppBase.java:140)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at com.test.AppBase.callSmth(AppBase.java:156)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at com.test.android.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-09 20:54:38.496: E/WindowManager(15895):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using MAT and get a dump from the DMMS in eclipse to analytize. It indicates me that there is a class in the java project that get most of the resources. There i use the webview, running on mainthread. If i try to initialize a webview on a non-mainuithread a warning appears and on some devices it just does not show the webview.

One of the webviews are integrated in a Dialog. From what i can understand is that when i try to dismiss the dialog, the reference to the Activity might not be there.

Sometimes i receive this error as well(no matter the device, for api > 10)

```
E/ActivityThread(16551): Pause GC
E/ActivityThread(16551): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(16551): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/St
ing;)I
E/ActivityThread(16551):        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(16551):        ... 15 more
```

I have searched this too and found out it's not the developer fault here(but i don't know if these two are linked. There is not much details in the stack trace), but on the above one it's for sure my code.

I don;t know what to try right now, should i not show the webview from the main thread?

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mWebView = MyWebViewFactory.create(mActivity, "");
                    dialog = MyWebViewFactory.showWebView(mActivity, mWebView);
                }
            });
```

and

```
public static Dialog showWebView(final Activity context, final WebView webView) {
        Dialog callAlert = new Dialog(context,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        callAlert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = callAlert.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        callAlert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        callAlert.setContentView(webView);
        callAlert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        callAlert.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        callAlert.getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        callAlert.setCancelable(true);
        return callAlert;
    }
```

Thanks.